# Why am I getting different behavior in my web app between Mouse.Click() and a hardware click in CodedUI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, coded-ui-tests, mouseclick-event

I'm working on a CodedUI Automated Testing suite for a couple different applications.

For the second time now, I'm encountering *explicit* differences between using Mouse.Click() on a control and actually clicking the control with a mouse. The latest problem centers around an input button. As far as I can tell the button submits an ASP.NET form. The web apps all use Telerik, if that's relevant at all.

When I order a Mouse.Click() on the UI element, the form presents a loading circle and freezes. 
[image: The app window after freezing. Besides red blocks, no alterations]

I want to say that at one point this thing did work when I clicked in my test. The same issue applies to a software-sent Keyboard.SendKeys("{Enter}"). When I click with my physical mouse *or* use my actual keyboard, the form submits, does the graphical loading spin, and comes back in <5s with no issue.

For the sake of completeness, a snippet:

```
Mouse.Click(maintControls.UIMaintSearchButton);
maintControls.UIMaintResultsTable.WaitForControlReady();
int NumOrgSearchRows = maintControls.UIMaintResultsTable.RowCount;
Assert.IsTrue(NumOrgSearchRows > 3
    , "blahblah Search Test Failed.  Search results were not displayed");
```

This is where the test fails. **Importantly**, the result table is still found and can give a number of rows - the issue is that it's what the table looked like before clicking search rather than after. For instance if the search "Cat" returned 4 results, and I entered "dog" before clicking search (which normally returns 10 rows) NumOrgSearchRows would be 4.

What is the difference between these two? What am I doing wrong? Is there a way (even if it's more complicated) to do a "real" click over just calling one from the .NET library? I feel like there should be 0 difference between these and I'm baffled.

Any and all theories welcome. Thanks!

Comment: What is the exception that you get? If the form submits and AJAX is involved, the control reference in CodedUI might be stale, that is the CodedUI control references a control that is no longer part of the page. This can happen if you reference an element in CodedUI that gets replaced by `element.innerHTML = "new HTML"` in a JavaScript AJAX callback.

Comment: Greg, there is no exception at this moment - the test looks at the result table and counts the rows. However the result table that it's able to access in the DOM is the one that existed before I click "Search" - not the one that should exist after. And if the mouse input was identical then I could at LEAST do a playback.wait() if I was being basic. The table simply never loads the new results when I call Mouse.Click()

Comment: Also I do believe Ajax is involved. The div that contains the table is a "RadAjaxPanel", which is a telerik element.

Comment: You could try doing a Mouse.Hover immediately before the Mouse.Click - I've seen some controls that rely on the mouse being hovered over them to activate some behaviour before the click happens. Long shot I'll admit.

Comment: @AdrianHofman Thanks for the suggestion. I still haven't found a "True" solution to this problem, but I suspect that it has something to do with my browser configuration, as my co-workers do not have this problem at the moment. This control does not require a hover.

However I HAVE been able to eliminate the problem about 50% of the time it occurs by using a generic method I've created. The method takes a CodedUI control and an offset integer (default value of 5) as parameters, then clicks a point within the control's bounding box. This may help others with some stubborn controls.